# AuthorizationException: {"type":0,"code":3,"errorDescription":"Network error"} : Appauth

Tags: android, openid-connect, appauth

I am following https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android for implementing Keycloak login using Appauth. I am getting AuthorizationException: {"type":0,"code":3,"errorDescription":"Network error"} sometimes when try to request token. Sometimes it is working fine and I am getting the response. I searched on internet and could not find a solution. Anybody knows a solution ?

I used following code for getting the token

```
authService.performTokenRequest(
resp.createTokenExchangeRequest(),
new AuthorizationService.TokenResponseCallback() {
  @Override public void onTokenRequestCompleted(
        TokenResponse resp, AuthorizationException ex) {
      if (resp != null) {
        // exchange succeeded
      } else {
        // authorization failed, check ex for more details
      }
    }
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok, similar to [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/authguidance/basicmobileapp/plumbing/oauth/AuthenticatorImpl.kt#L268).

The message that is failing should look like [step 10 of my blog post](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/29/basicandroidapp-execution/). When I get issues like this I proceed by tracing HTTPS messages in order to better understand the cause. Step 7 of the blog post links to an HTTPS tracing setup in case that helps.